# Query To Sum Order Totals

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I have two tables that I need to pull data from.  I need to produce an order total in the query.  Should be straight forward, but I get inaccurate results for anyone who has multiple orders.  This is my DDL

```
Create Table #first
(
  userid varchar(100)
  ,orderqty int
  ,orderprice float
  ,orderdesc varchar(500)
  ,orderdate datetime
)
Create Table #second
(
  userid varchar(100)
  ,orderstatus varchar(100)
  ,orderreviewstatus varchar(100)
)

Insert Into #first VALUES
('emp12', '14', '10', 'firstorder', '2016-08-11 13:59:23.363')
,('bla', '1', '20', 'red socks', '2016-08-11 13:59:23.363')
,('gra23', '2', '4', 'black coat', '2016-08-11 13:59:23.363')
,('meh33', '5', '2', 'orange socks', '2016-08-11 13:59:23.363')
,('meh33', '3', '1', 'blue trousers', '2016-08-13 13:59:23.363')

Insert Into #second VALUES
('emp12', 'Shipped', 'Reviewed')
,('bla', 'Shipped', 'Reviewed')
,('gra23', 'Shipped', 'Reviewed')
,('meh33', 'Shipped', 'Reviewed')
,('meh33', NULL, NULL)
```

In this example only userid meh33 has two orders, and this is my query I am using

```
Select
a.userid
,a.orderqty
,a.orderprice
,SUM(a.orderqty*a.orderprice) As OrderTotal
,a.orderdesc
,a.orderdate
,b.orderstatus
,b.orderreviewstatus
FROM #first a
INNER JOIN #second b
ON a.userid = b.userid
GROUP BY a.userid, a.orderqty, a.orderprice, a.orderdesc, a.orderdate,     b.orderstatus, b.orderreviewstatus
```

This is the output that this query produces (notice the multiple entries for meh33:

```
userid  orderqty    orderprice  OrderTotal  orderdesc   orderdate   orderstatus orderreviewstatus
bla 1   20  20  red socks   2016-08-11 13:59:23.363 Shipped Reviewed
emp12   14  10  140 firstorder  2016-08-11 13:59:23.363 Shipped Reviewed
gra23   2   4   8   black coat  2016-08-11 13:59:23.363 Shipped Reviewed
meh33   3   1   3   blue trousers   2016-08-13 13:59:23.363 NULL    NULL
meh33   3   1   3   blue trousers   2016-08-13 13:59:23.363 Shipped Reviewed
meh33   5   2   10  orange socks    2016-08-11 13:59:23.363 NULL    NULL
meh33   5   2   10  orange socks    2016-08-11 13:59:23.363 Shipped Reviewed
```

And this is my desired output: (one row for each order)

```
userid  orderqty    orderprice  OrderTotal  orderdesc   orderdate   orderstatus orderreviewstatus
bla 1 20 20 red socks 2016-08-11 13:59:23.363 Shipped Reviewed
emp12 14 10 140 firstorder 2016-08-11 13:59:23.363 Shipped Reviewed
gra23 2 4 8 black coat 2016-08-11 13:59:23.363 Shipped Reviewed 
meh33 5 2 10 orange socks 2016-08-11 13:59:23.363 Shipped Reviewed
meh33 3 1 3 blue trousers 2016-08-13 13:59:23.363
```

What must I alter in my query in order to get my desired result set returned?

Comment: Are you able to modify the table schema?  That is really what is needed here as there is no way of linking the two different orders to each other.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to modify table structure (that would alleviate 200% of the problems if I could.)

Comment: You can't do this reliably then. There needs to be something that says that it is the Orange Socks order that was `Shipped Reviewed` rather than the Blue Trousers one.

Comment: Would the query reliably return results if I ONLY returned an orderqty and an orderprice?  Or would those results be skewed also?

Comment: There is no way the example data you have presented can ever return reliable results. SQL Server can't guess which of meh33's orders in table 1 matches to that in table 2.

Comment: If you only returned OrderQty and OrderPrice then you would not be pulling any data back from #Second so you could remove that join.  In that case you would only end up with one row per order.

Comment: In your desired result, why does `shipped, reviewed` apply to `orange socks` instead of `blue trousers`? This schema seems to support only one order per user so the many-to-many join will inherently return duplicates.  But if `#second` contains only information for the earliest order, this is doable.

Comment: I agree with what others have said, there is no - obvious - way to determine if blue trousers or orange socks have been shipped. Also noted is that there are no keys defined in your tables, I would start by thinking about what identifies a tuple in each of the tables. Once decided you probably need to clean some of the data before adding those keys.

Comment: Usually there's an Order Number assigned to each order, if your datamodel is missing it you're doomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change you **GROUP BY** and **SELECT** clauses. Also, I'd use Order_ID instead of description to sort.

```
Select a.userid ,
       SUM(a.orderqty) AS OrderQtyTotal ,
       SUM(a.orderprice) AS OrderPriceTotal ,
       SUM(a.orderqty*a.orderprice) AS OrderTotal ,
       a.orderdesc ,
       MAX(a.orderdate) AS LatestOrderDate ,
       MAX(b.orderstatus) AS LatestOrderStatus ,
       MAX(b.orderreviewstatus) AS LatestOrderViewStatus 
FROM #first a INNER JOIN #second b ON a.userid = b.userid 
GROUP BY a.userid, a.orderdesc
```